# Shared Element Transition not working on Android Nougat (API 25)

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

Facing problems with Shared Element transition animation on Android 7 (Nougat)

In my case Activity A calls Activity B using shared element transition and pressing back on B finishes it and shows A. Now on A onStart is never called.

Working fine on previous versions of Android.

Strange behaviour. Need help

Comment: Please paste your code here

Comment: I'm facing the same problem.. have you found a solution?

Comment: @Katharina - No, i did not find any solution yet. Also please answer here if you find any solution.

Comment: seems like it worked?

Comment: Great. Are you getting the event inside onStart() ?

Comment: awesome :) yep - onStart() is called now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by defining the enter and exit transitions in code instead of defining it in `themes.xml` -> I removed the following lines of  code from the `themes.xml`:

```
 <item name="android:windowEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        @transition/fade
    </item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        @transition/fade_out
    </item>

    <item name="android:windowReturnTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        @transition/fade_out
    </item>

    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        @transition/change_image_trans
    </item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        @transition/change_image_trans_out
    </item>

    <item name="android:windowSharedElementReturnTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        @transition/change_image_trans_out
    </item>
```

And added the following lines to my activities (you have to add in `onCreate` before adding any content to the activity):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // inside your activity (if you did not enable transitions in your theme)
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
        // set an enter transition

        getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Explode());
        // set an exit transition
        getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
    }
```

With this code I just set the transitions for the activity - if you also want to change the content transitions you need to call `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);`